# Scripts doesn't work after a page transition in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, transition

i am new using jQuery Mobile and i didn't found a solution after hours looking for it.

I have two pages, the initial has a form that when you click the Sent button makes a transition to other page. In the second page i have a new form but it doesn't work after the page transition. But if i enter into the second page directly from the navigation bar with the url the second form works perfectly.
When the second page is loaded from the first with changePage() method it doesn't do anything.

To test it i have the following code in the first page:

```
<a data-icon="home" id="botonLogin" data-theme="a" data-role="button">Entrar</a>
```

And this code for handle the click event:

```
$("a#botonLogin").bind("click", function(event) {
    $.mobile.changePage( "busqueda.php", { transition: "flip"} );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it on this way:

```
$('div#busqueda').bind('pageshow',function(event, ui){
    //The code of the second page here.
}
```